# Ajax and string manipulation to form an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string

I'm using ajax to get some date from the server, I'm then using an ugly hack to manipulate the string data that is returned into an array.  The code works, but is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
function findUsers(date){
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "user_dates",
  cache: false,
  data: {matched_date:date},
  success: function(html){
    user_arry = [];
    $("#hidden_div").append(html);
    a = $("#hidden_div").html();

    b = a.substring(2, 6);
    c = a.substring(10, 14);
    d = a.substring(18, 22);

    user_arry.push(b,c,d);
    for (var j in user_arry) {
    (hidden_array = '\.'+ user_arry[j]);
    $(hidden_array).hide();
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't make sense - you're completely overwriting the value of `hidden_array` with each loop. What is the result of the request and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: hidden_array is just user_arry with a '.' attached to each element.  The result of the request is ["0700", "0800", "1800"] but this is just a string which I then turn into an array.

Answer (score 0):

On server side

```
<?php

json_encode($yourdata);

?>
```

And client side.

```
function findUsers(date){
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "user_dates",
  cache: false,
  data: {matched_date:date},
  success: function(data){
   var yourobj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   //use your object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need user_array? Why not assign b,c,d directly to hidden_array?
You could name your variables better. You also could work with regular expressions instead of substrings. But be careful. Do not make the code more unreadable. At last, you could extract the code into an own method.
But using json with jquery would be the best:)

[sven.malvik.de](http://sven.malvik.de)

Answer (score 0):

don't forget the 'dataType' properties on client side:

```
[...]
cache: false,
data: _yourData,
dataType: 'json',
[...]
```